# Is vs Are when subjects are -ing

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, compound-subjects

Original sentence:

> Even being paid very well, and enjoying great working conditions, **is** not enough.

Should not it be this?

> Even being paid very well, and enjoying great working conditions, **are** not enough.

Or are both acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> Even being paid very well is not enough.
>
> Even enjoying great working conditions is not enough.
>
> Even being paid very well and enjoying great working conditions are not enough.

Because once you've gotten to that point, you have two things in your subject.  That's enough to be plural.

According to https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/moduleSVAGR.htm

> Although each part of the compound subject is singular (ranger and camper), taken together (joined by and), each one becomes a part of a plural structure and, therefore, must take a plural verb (see) to agree in the sentence.
>
> SUBJECT-VERB RULE #1 – Two or more singular (or plural) subjects joined by and act as a plural compound subject and take a plural verb (singular + singular = plural).

Comment: Are you sure? After all, toast and jam makes a nice breakfast.

Comment: I think toast and jam makes a nice breakfast because it's understood they're combined into a single item. But there are also common word usages that are objectively wrong by the language, because unfortunately, the English language predates the rules and is often spoken by fallible humans...